# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < using CakePhP

Tags: javascript, cakephp

I'm meeting a small problem with CakePhp... When I get an url like http://www.example.com/news/delete:5 , I always get this javascript error message, no matter what param I want to transfer through the url.

> jquery-2.1.4.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   jquery-ui.min.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

In those files, at the first line.

Anyone can help me please? Thank you!

Comment: I usually get that if the server responded with 200 and HTML instead of 404 when files are not found. Could that be a possibility?

Comment: You were close... In fact, for an unknown reason, jQuery didn't want to load from the webroot if I added something at the end of my links...
Thank you very much, it helped me finding the problem.